# Figure out which plugin is responsible for a key binding

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-system

I was about to answer a question but realized that my answer depends on a key binding provided by a plugin I have installed. Even worse, I don't know which plugin provides it.

The only way I know to solve this problem would be to "binary search" my installed plugins by disabling half and enabling the other half. I use Vundle to manage my plugins so each iteration would only require me to comment out part of a plugin list but that's still a clumsy procedure.

Is there a better way to determine which plugin is responsible for a given key binding? Is there a way to determine if a given key binding is instead provided by my `vimrc` file directly?

I realize Vim doesn't have a builtin notion of plugins, so maybe the question is more precisely phrased as "How can I determine which file containing vimscript is responsible for a given key binding?".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the following: `:verbose map <c-p>` replacing `<c-p>` with the key bind you're looking for. Prints something like this:

`Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/plugin/ctrlp.vim`