# Is there any way to influence how `i_CTRL-W` defines a word boundary of a word to be deleted?

Tags: insert-mode

**Problem**: I want to be able to quickly remove the last typed word while remaining in the Insert mode. However, `i_CTRL-W` seems to be using `WORD` definition of a word. I.e. it is not possible to just remove 'word' in `word-word-word` even with `iskeyword=@,48-57,192-255,_,-`

In `:help i_CTRL-W`, I'm advised to `See the section "word motions", |word-motions|, for the definition of a word.` It is however unclear how its contents apply to `i_CTRL-W`.

Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Not for me. Can you reproduce this behaviour with `vim -Nu NONE`? If not, it might be a plugin or mapping at work.

Comment: If you can, include the output of `:verb imap <C-w>` in your post. If a plugin has modified the behavior of `<C-w>`, maybe its filename will appear.

Comment: @saginaw: Adding `:verb` in front of a `map` command to see where was the mapping made is a pretty cool trick! I don't remember seeing something like this on this site maybe that would be worth a self-answered question or something like that.

Comment: @statox Thank you very much ! But I think the question / answer has already been done here: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/279/4939

Comment: Thanks for hints! Works as intended. This was my misinterpretation of `iskeyword`. Posted an answer just in case someone makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by comments to the question, `iskeyword` actually has to influence `i_CTRL-W` behavior and it indeed does. This was my misinterpretation of `iskeyword` being a set of delimiters but it is of course a set of word characters instead.

So no wonder that having a `'-'` in `iskeyword` does not remove a single instance of *'word'* from `word-word-word` but all of it at once because it is considered to be a single word.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. When I said, not for me, I meant that `<c-w>` did delete only up to `-`, it did not delete all of it.

Comment: If I fire up `vim -Nu NONE`, then `-` is not in `iskeyword` and vim does not delete `word-word-word` at once but only the last `word` up to `-`. But in my question I used `iskeyword` **with** `-` and I wondered why this deletes all of it.